# There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_file_write’ at (1)

Tags: fortran, cygwin, gfortran, openmpi, mpich

**I am trying to compile a Linux source file on Windows with the tool Cygwin. When I try to make, error occurs:**

```
mpif90 -c -O3 -I/usr/include -Iobj -Jobj -o obj/sdf_output_point_ru.o 
src/io/sdf_output_point_ru.f90
src/io/sdf_output_point_ru.f90:260:39:

         MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, errcode)
                                   1
error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_file_write’ at (1)
src/io/sdf_output_point_ru.f90:265:37:

       MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, errcode)
                                 1
error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_file_write’ at (1)
make: *** [Makefile:166：sdf_output_point_ru.o] error 1
```

**The original source file of sdf_output_point_ru.o file is as follows:**

```
MODULE sdf_output_point_ru

  USE mpi
  USE sdf_common
  USE sdf_output

  IMPLICIT NONE

CONTAINS

  SUBROUTINE write_point_mesh_meta_r8(h, id, name, dim_labels, dim_units, &
      dim_mults)

    TYPE(sdf_file_handle) :: h
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: id, name
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: dim_labels(:), dim_units(:)
    REAL(r8), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: dim_mults
    INTEGER :: ndims
    TYPE(sdf_block_type), POINTER :: b
    INTEGER :: i, errcode

    b => h%current_block

    b%blocktype = c_blocktype_point_mesh
    ndims = b%ndims
    b%nelements = b%ndims * b%npoints

    ! Metadata is
    ! - mults     REAL(r8), DIMENSION(ndims)
    ! - labels    CHARACTER(id_length), DIMENSION(ndims)
    ! - units     CHARACTER(id_length), DIMENSION(ndims)
    ! - geometry  INTEGER(i4)
    ! - minval    REAL(r8), DIMENSION(ndims)
    ! - maxval    REAL(r8), DIMENSION(ndims)
    ! - npoints   INTEGER(i8)

    b%info_length = h%block_header_length + soi4 + soi8 &
        + (3 * ndims) * sof8 + 2 * ndims * c_id_length
    b%data_length = b%nelements * b%type_size

    ! Write header

    IF (PRESENT(id)) THEN
      ALLOCATE(b%dim_labels(ndims), b%dim_units(ndims), b%dim_mults(ndims))

      IF (PRESENT(dim_labels)) THEN
        DO i = 1,ndims
          CALL safe_copy_string(dim_labels(i), b%dim_labels(i))
        ENDDO
      ELSE
        IF (ndims .GE. 1) CALL safe_copy_string('X', b%dim_labels(1))
        IF (ndims .GE. 2) CALL safe_copy_string('Y', b%dim_labels(2))
        IF (ndims .GE. 3) CALL safe_copy_string('Z', b%dim_labels(3))
      ENDIF

      IF (PRESENT(dim_units)) THEN
        DO i = 1,ndims
          CALL safe_copy_string(dim_units(i), b%dim_units(i))
        ENDDO
      ELSE
        DO i = 1,ndims
          CALL safe_copy_string('m', b%dim_units(i))
        ENDDO
      ENDIF

      IF (PRESENT(dim_mults)) THEN
        DO i = 1,ndims
          b%dim_mults(i) = REAL(dim_mults(i),r8)
        ENDDO
      ELSE
        DO i = 1,ndims
          b%dim_mults(i) = 1.d0
        ENDDO
      ENDIF

      CALL sdf_write_block_header(h, id, name)
    ELSE
      CALL write_block_header(h)
    ENDIF

    IF (h%rank .EQ. h%rank_master) THEN
      CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE(h%filehandle, b%dim_mults, ndims, MPI_REAL8, &
          MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, errcode)

      DO i = 1,ndims
        CALL sdf_safe_write_id(h, b%dim_labels(i))
      ENDDO

      DO i = 1,ndims
        CALL sdf_safe_write_id(h, b%dim_units(i))
      ENDDO

      CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE(h%filehandle, b%geometry, 1, MPI_INTEGER4, &
          MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, errcode)

      CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE(h%filehandle, b%extents, 2 * ndims, MPI_REAL8, &
          MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, errcode)

      CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE(h%filehandle, b%npoints, 1, MPI_INTEGER8, &
          MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, errcode)
    ENDIF

    h%current_location = b%block_start + b%info_length
    b%done_info = .TRUE.

  END SUBROUTINE write_point_mesh_meta_r8



  SUBROUTINE write_point_mesh_meta_r4(h, id, name, dim_labels, dim_units, &
      dim_mults)

    TYPE(sdf_file_handle) :: h
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: id, name
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: dim_labels(:), dim_units(:)
    REAL(r4), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: dim_mults
    REAL(r8), DIMENSION(c_maxdims) :: dim_mults8
    TYPE(sdf_block_type), POINTER :: b
    INTEGER :: i

    IF (PRESENT(dim_mults)) THEN
      b => h%current_block
      DO i = 1,b%ndims
        dim_mults8(i) = REAL(dim_mults(i),r8)
      ENDDO
      CALL write_point_mesh_meta_r8(h, id, name, dim_labels, dim_units, &
          dim_mults8)
    ELSE
      CALL write_point_mesh_meta_r8(h, id, name, dim_labels, dim_units)
    ENDIF

  END SUBROUTINE write_point_mesh_meta_r4



  SUBROUTINE write_point_variable_meta_r8(h, id, name, units, mesh_id, mult)

    TYPE(sdf_file_handle) :: h
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: id, name, units
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: mesh_id
    REAL(r8), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: mult
    INTEGER :: ndims
    TYPE(sdf_block_type), POINTER :: b
    INTEGER :: errcode

    b => h%current_block

    b%blocktype = c_blocktype_point_variable
    ndims = b%ndims
    b%nelements = b%ndims * b%npoints

    ! Metadata is
    ! - mult      REAL(r8)
    ! - units     CHARACTER(id_length)
    ! - meshid    CHARACTER(id_length)
    ! - npoints   INTEGER(i8)

    b%info_length = h%block_header_length + soi8 + sof8 + 2 * c_id_length
    b%data_length = b%nelements * b%type_size

    ! Write header

    IF (PRESENT(id)) THEN
      CALL safe_copy_string(units, b%units)
      CALL safe_copy_string(mesh_id, b%mesh_id)

      IF (PRESENT(mult)) THEN
        b%mult = REAL(mult,r8)
      ELSE
        b%mult = 1.d0
      ENDIF

      CALL sdf_write_block_header(h, id, name)
    ELSE
      CALL write_block_header(h)
    ENDIF

    IF (h%rank .EQ. h%rank_master) THEN
      CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE(h%filehandle, b%mult, 1, MPI_REAL8, &
          MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, errcode)

      CALL sdf_safe_write_id(h, b%units)

      CALL sdf_safe_write_id(h, b%mesh_id)

      CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE(h%filehandle, b%npoints, 1, MPI_INTEGER8, &
          MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, errcode)
    ENDIF

    h%current_location = b%block_start + b%info_length
    b%done_info = .TRUE.

  END SUBROUTINE write_point_variable_meta_r8



  SUBROUTINE write_point_variable_meta_r4(h, id, name, units, mesh_id, mult)

    TYPE(sdf_file_handle) :: h
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: id, name, units
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: mesh_id
    REAL(r4), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: mult

    IF (PRESENT(mult)) THEN
      CALL write_point_variable_meta_r8(h, id, name, units, mesh_id, &
          REAL(mult,r8))
    ELSE
      CALL write_point_variable_meta_r8(h, id, name, units, mesh_id)
    ENDIF

  END SUBROUTINE write_point_variable_meta_r4



  SUBROUTINE write_srl_pt_var_int_i8_r8(h, id, name, units, array, &
      npoint_global, mesh_id, mult)

    TYPE(sdf_file_handle) :: h
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: id, name, units
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: array
    INTEGER(i8), INTENT(IN) :: npoint_global
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: mesh_id
    REAL(r8), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: mult
    INTEGER(i8) :: i, idx, npoint_max, npoint_rem
    INTEGER :: errcode
    TYPE(sdf_block_type), POINTER :: b

    IF (npoint_global .LE. 0) RETURN

    CALL sdf_get_next_block(h)
    b => h%current_block

    b%type_size = INT(h%soi,r4)
    b%datatype = h%datatype_integer
    b%mpitype = h%mpitype_integer
    b%ndims = 1
    b%npoints = npoint_global

    ! Write header

    CALL write_point_variable_meta_r8(h, id, name, units, mesh_id, mult)

    ! Write the real data

    IF (h%rank .EQ. h%rank_master) THEN
      h%current_location = b%data_location
      CALL MPI_FILE_SEEK(h%filehandle, h%current_location, MPI_SEEK_SET, &
          errcode)

      ! This is all a bit messy, but it is necessary because MPI_FILE_WRITE
      ! accepts an INTEGER count of elements to write, which may not be
      ! big enough for npoint_global which is an INTEGER*8

      npoint_max = HUGE(npoint_max)
      npoint_rem = MOD(npoint_global, npoint_max)

      idx = 1
      DO i = 1, npoint_global / npoint_max
        CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE(h%filehandle, array(idx), npoint_max, b%mpitype, &
            MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, errcode)
        idx = idx + npoint_max
      ENDDO

      CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE(h%filehandle, array(idx), npoint_rem, b%mpitype, &
          MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, errcode)
    ENDIF

    h%current_location = b%data_location + b%data_length
    b%done_data = .TRUE.

  END SUBROUTINE write_srl_pt_var_int_i8_r8



  SUBROUTINE write_srl_pt_var_int_i4_r8(h, id, name, units, array, &
      npoint_global, mesh_id, mult)

    TYPE(sdf_file_handle) :: h
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: id, name, units
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: array
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: npoint_global
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: mesh_id
    REAL(r8), INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: mult

    CALL write_srl_pt_var_int_i8_r8(h, id, name, units, array, &
        INT(npoint_global,i8), mesh_id, mult)

  END SUBROUTINE write_srl_pt_var_int_i4_r8



  SUBROUTINE write_srl_pt_var_int_i8_r4(h, id, name, units, array, &
      npoint_global, mesh_id, mult)

    TYPE(sdf_file_handle) :: h
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: id, name, units
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: array
    INTEGER(i8), INTENT(IN) :: npoint_global
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: mesh_id
    REAL(r4), INTENT(IN) :: mult

    CALL write_srl_pt_var_int_i8_r8(h, id, name, units, array, &
        npoint_global, mesh_id, REAL(mult,r8))

  END SUBROUTINE write_srl_pt_var_int_i8_r4



  SUBROUTINE write_srl_pt_var_int_i4_r4(h, id, name, units, array, &
      npoint_global, mesh_id, mult)

    TYPE(sdf_file_handle) :: h
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: id, name, units
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: array
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: npoint_global
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: mesh_id
    REAL(r4), INTENT(IN) :: mult

    CALL write_srl_pt_var_int_i8_r8(h, id, name, units, array, &
        INT(npoint_global,i8), mesh_id, REAL(mult,r8))

  END SUBROUTINE write_srl_pt_var_int_i4_r4

END MODULE sdf_output_point_ru
```

Comment: Due to the length of the file and the number of mpi_file_write calls  please also indicate lines line 260 and line 265 where the errors are.

Comment: Welcome, please read [mcve]. We cannot test your code, because we can't compile it because we do not have your modules `sdf_common` and `sdf_output`. Also, the code is too long, the error is aonly about a few lines and you should be able to isolate a much smaller example to test. You might be able to find the error yourself when preparing the test for us.

Comment: The general advice for this kind of error is always the same. You must take the manual and check the type of every variable in the subroutine call. One (or more) of them is wrong.

Comment: the error could be you declare both `npoint_max` and `npoint_rem` as `INTEGER(i8)` and `MPI_File_write()` expects an `INTEGER`

Comment: Have you installed `libopenmpi-devel` ?

Comment: Yes, `libopenmpi-devel` is already installed. And the source code was successfully compiled on Ubuntu. So I'm wondering whether it's Cygwin itself causing the error. I'm quite confused.

Comment: Have you read the comment of @GillesGouaillardet above? Did you follow his advice? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes, I've read the comment of @GillesGouaillardet. After declaring both `npoint_max` and `npoint_rem` as `INTEGER`, the compiling process went well. Thank you both. @GillesGouaillardet @Vladimir